# Improving a double conversion method

Tags: c#, double

I currently have the following 2 methods:

```
public static Point[] PolygonFromFile(string file)
    {
        string[] GBfile = File.ReadAllLines(file);

        // remove unnecessary data from first 2 lines, never contains any polygon data
        GBfile[0] = string.Empty;
        GBfile[1] = string.Empty;

        const string delim = "   ";

        List<string> points = (from s in GBfile where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) from i in s.Split(delim.ToCharArray()) where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i) && i != "END" select i).ToList();

        List<Point> polygon = new List<Point>();

        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count / 2; i++)
        {
            polygon.Add(new Point
            {
                X = PointParse(points[i]),
                Y = PointParse(points[i + 1])
            });
        }

        return polygon.ToArray();
    }

    private static double PointParse(string value)
    {
        string[] parsed = value.Split("E".ToCharArray());

        char function = '\0';
        bool met = false;

        foreach (char c in parsed[1])
        {
            if (c == '-' || c == '+')
            {
                function = c;
                break;
            }
        }

        var splitMultiplier = parsed[1].Split(function);
        double decimalPlaces = Convert.ToDouble(splitMultiplier[1]);

        if (decimalPlaces == 0) return Convert.ToDouble(parsed[0]);

        switch (function)
        {
            case '+':
                return Convert.ToDouble(parsed[0]) * Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
            case '-':
                return Convert.ToDouble(parsed[0]) / Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

That will convert a value such as `5.807600E-02` to the true value of `0.058076`.

I feel like this is an extremely verbose way of achieving what I need to, is there a function in C# to achieve this or do I need to go through the above process to convert the given value to the necessary one?

Comment: Maybe it is not the question you have been asked, but when this method is called it creates temporary the data four times: First the file content as string array, second as list of strings where a few entries are removed, as third a list of points and at last an array of the same points. Depending on the size of your file this can lead to memory problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET can parse these values on its own

```
Double.Parse("5.807600E-02");
```

will return the value 0.058076 as a double.

Comment: Well that feels like a wasted few hours, I'll accept your answer when I can. Thanks!

Comment: @JayGould I only know because I did the same thing a while back :)

Comment: The more I look at my code for this the more I want to headbutt my desk :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
double d = Double.Parse("1.2345E-03", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parse function. Try this.

```
decimal d = Decimal.Parse("5.807600E-02",System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```